# How can I loop through json in the gsp each tag?

Tags: json, grails, groovy, gsp

I have the following code:

```
<g:each var="question" in="${confHolder.config.faq}">
  <h1>${question.question}</h1>
  <h1>${question.answer}</h1>
</g:each>
```

In my conf file I have the following json:

```
faq = [{"question":"What is this", "answer":"This thing"}, {"question":"What is this", "answer":"This thing"}];
```

I know that I'm reading in the file correctly because I can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var faq = ${confHolder.config.faq} 
  for(var ii=0; ii<faq.length; ii++)
    alert(faq[0].question);
</script>
```

And it will alert out my question.

How can I loop through my json in the `each` tag and print out the questions and answers in the `<h1></h1>` tag?

Comment: Is your conf file some sort of JavaScript file? Or do you mean Config.groovy? If the former, you can't as the gsp is server side and the data is client side, so you'll need a JavaScript solution

Comment: What is the exact line you have in grails-app/conf/Config.groovy then? The line in your question isn't valid groovy

Comment: So it's actually a .properties file that get's pulled into the config with grails.config.locations = ["file:resources/faq.properties"]

Comment: Right, so it's a string. Try `<g:each var="question" in="${new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText( confHolder.config.faq )}">`

Comment: Thanks for you help so far!  I added that line and it said "unable to resolve class groovy.json.JsonSlurper." So I tried to add <%@ page import="groovy.json*" %> at the top of my .gsp file but I still got the error.  Any ideas?

Comment: What version of grails is this?

Comment: Grails 1.3.7 and I can't upgrade until the summer.

Comment: Can you move the FAQ variable into Config.groovy so it can be a map rather than a string? Grails 1.3.7 is pre groovy 1.8 when JsonSlurper was added to groovy

Comment: It needs to be in it's own separate file.  Would it help if it was in a .groovy file? As json somehow?

Comment: Actually try `grails.converters.JSON.parse( confHolder.config.faq )`

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Do you mind making this an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Yay, Done :-D good luck with it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse the json into a list of maps:

This should work for grails 1.3.7

```
<g:each var="question" in="${grails.converters.JSON.parse( confHolder.config.faq )}">
```